# position()=1 working correctly, but not position()<5

Tags: xslt, foreach

I'm new to XSLT, and I'm carrying out a few tests using w3schools "Try it yourself"  pages. I'm using the following demo:

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=tryxsl_choose

This contains the following line:

```
<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
```

I'm testing filtering the HTML rendered by `position()` but I'm having issues when using the `<` operand.

---

I've tried the following:

```
<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd[position()=1]">
```

And this returns the first item from the XML data (as expected).

---

I then tried:

```
<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd[position()<5]">
```

I was expecting this to return the first 4 items, but instead I get no results.

My guess is that perhaps `position()=1` is doing a string comparison, which is why it returns the first item, but it cannot understand `position()<5` as a string cannot be compared in this way?

Why is this happening, and what would be the correct syntax to get the results I wish to achieve?

---

**Update:** After reading @joocer's response, and testing this myself, using the `>` operand does work, for the opposite result:

```
<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd[(position()>5)]">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even inside quotes, you must type `<` as `&lt;` so it won't be confused for the start of an element tag. I think this was done to make it easier for tolerant parsers to recover from errors and streaming parsers skip content faster. They can always look for `<` outside `CDATA` and know that is an element start or end tag.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work either :S `<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd[position()&lt;5]">`. Try editing the following and it returns 0 results http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=tryxsl_choose

Comment: Odd. I got this information right from the second note here http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#booleans. It shouldn't matter, but try adding whitespace on either side of the `&lt;`

Comment: I think Michael Kay is right and that this is a bug with libxslt, which explains why `&lt;` cannot be used. I've tested on a ASP.NET application and it works fine with `&lt;` and throws an exception when using `<`. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

It looks very much like a bug in the version of libxslt that w3schools is using.

Comment: It seems to have emerged that the problem with the w3schools test bed is that they corrupt "<" signs entered into their text area.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why, but inverting the condition works, so instead of looking for less than 5, look for not more than 4

```
<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd[not(position()>4)]">
```

Comment: +1 This works thanks, although I'm still interested to know why `<` doesn't work.